# Laptop screen brightness is often only fully bright or fully dim

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, brightness

Full disclosure: This is a company-owned laptop. I am an IT professional responsible for keeping this laptop running, along with several hundred of its siblings and ancestors.

This issue has happened on multiple computers. I have only used laptops of the same model myself and so will focus on this.

This is a Dell Latitude 7400 2-in-1, running Windows 10 20H2, fully patched. The issue is only with the integrated display on the laptop.

From time to time, ranging from a few times each day to once or twice a week, the laptop screen will only allow either fully bright or fully dim in its brightness settings. Using the F5 and F6 keys to brighten and dim the screen, I see the indicator showing brightness going up or down, appropriate to the key I'm pressing, but the screen is fully bright in every position along that indicator other than all the way down at the bottom, when the screen immediately goes to fully dimmed.

The system is still remembering the brightness level selected, because as I leave the system for a while with the brightness indicated at, for instance, 50%, when I begin pressing the F5 (to reduce brightness) or F6 (to increase brightness) the indicator begins at 50% where I'd left it previously.

However, there are only two brightness levels effectively applied: When the indicator is all the way down the screen is as dim as it can go, and when the indicator is in any other position, beginning just one point above fully down and extending all the way to the top of its path, the screen runs at full brightness.

Typically, restarting the computer resolves the issue for a period of time, but not every time.

The issue switches between this fully-dim/fully-bright duality and normal graduated brightness levels usually during a power state event, such as sleeping, screen closed (off) but system still on (docked/connected to power), or restarting. But it doesn't do this every time.

I've assumed it was a driver issue, and so I've downloaded the latest drivers from Dell, and also from Intel (integrated graphics), as well as updated the system BIOS.

I rather assume this is something I'll need to report to Dell to have them fix, but I wanted to see if there was any knowledge or expertise here regarding something I may have overlooked or been unaware of that could solve this.

Comment: Update BIOS, Chipset and Power Driver and then restart the laptop and see if that helps. It might. Then if not, report to Dell as you said above.

Comment: We cannot help with company owned PC's unfortunately.

Comment: @Moab I'm the IT guy who keeps the company owned computers running. We have allowed that exception in the past. We don't allow people who are not IT to solicit help fixing problems their IT needs to fix, but that is not this case.

Comment: @John I'm afraid that will be the case. I'm hoping there might be some aspect of Windows 10 I'm missing regarding this, but that chance seems to be slipping.

Comment: The only other thought I have is that Dell has a battery manager (like Lenovo machines) . Look through those settings to see if anything pops up. Also look for a newer version of that software.

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: Laptop screen brightness is often only fully bright or fully dim

Comment: @GloriaGu um, no. I've had laptops for decades and not one of them have been only ever bright or dim. Further, as the question states, when it isn't acting faulty the screen dims and brightens in steps as the appropriate buttons are pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being hardware. The issue began getting worse, more common and persistent, and other issue began cropping up as well, and so I contacted warranty support. The computer ended up being shipped to a repair depot where most of the system components were replaced, and the issue has not reoccured since.